# Docker Best Practises: at what size application should you refrain from containerising?

Tags: docker

In my ongoing quest to Containerize All The Things, I've played with and installed some pretty hefty images. Not as crazy as what [Jessie Frazelle](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/) does, but still.

I have one that is 1.8 GB in size at which it hit me whether I may be heading into anti-pattern territory. I mean, where does it end? Dockerize the entire suite of Oracle products?!

Is there an advisory, guideline, best practise guide, anything that states at what point you should just stick with good old servers, VMs or similar?

I ran across a blog that said that SQL database servers is pretty much one where it's not worth it: by nature they are not immutable and you're looking at lots of mapped volumes anyway. Naturally I can't find that blog anymore. :(

At one point I ran nearly the entire suite of *Atlassian* products (*Bitbucket, Jira, Confluence, Bamboo*) in containers, with massive `docker run` command lines to get all the mappings and environments settings in. I stopped doing it when I just couldn't see the advantage.

Is there a good rule of thumb? A simple formula that encompasses, say, immutability and size to arrive at a "OK to containerise/DON'T containerise" table?

Comment: I don't think that image size is useful metric by which to make the "containerize/don't containerize" decision.  But, as you can see by the fact that I started with "I don't think..." this is primarily a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I'd love to see it in form of an answer that outlines why it's a bad metric (and I'm not debating that!), in that it doesn't have too much of an impact and is outweighed by other advantages. :) Maybe the tech is still simply too new overall to give us metrics like this. I think many of us are still going about it by trial&error.